# UIImage AsPNG and AsJPEG fails

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata, xamarin.ios

I'm using MonoTouch and I have a `UIImage` (displayed in a `UIImageView` and it looks good) and I'm trying to convert it to `NSData`, but `AsJPEG` and `AsPNG` returns `null`. What can be the problem?

My code looks like this:

```
NSError err;
NSData imageData = CroppedImageView.Image.AsJPEG(); // imageData is null!

if (!imageData.Save ("tmp.png", true, out err)) {
  Console.WriteLine("Saving of file failed: " + err.Description);
}
```

Comment: Why not check to see if the pieces before "`AsJPEG`" (e.g. "`.Image`" and "`CroppedImageView`") are not NULL as well?

Comment: I've checked it with the debugger they are not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AsJPEG returned null because the image size was too big (it was taken with an iPhone 5). After I Scaled it down by 2, it generates the data properly.

Answer (score 3):

The `AsJPEG` method calls `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and its return value is [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) as:

> A data object containing the JPEG data, or nil if there was a problem generating the data. This function may return nil if the image has no data or if the underlying CGImageRef contains data in an unsupported bitmap format.

The is similar to many API in iOS (and OSX) where exception are not commonly used (and `null` is used to report some kind of error).

Anyway you should check your image dimensions and properties - they might give you an hint at something that would not translate into a JPEG bitmap.

Also since the `NSData` can represent a very large amount of memory you should try to limit it's life, e.g.:

```
using (NSData imageData = CroppedImageView.Image.AsJPEG ()) {
   NSError err;
   if (!imageData.Save ("tmp.jpg", true, out err)) {
      Console.WriteLine("Saving of file failed: " + err.Description);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually in the end the problem was that the image was too big. I'm not sure how could that be a problem, because I've used the same code/same image size in my native iOS app and it worked fine. I've Scaled down the image by 2 and now it saves it properly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are writing to a file in the current directory of the app, this is readonly.

You should use:

`var path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFilename();`

or

`var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "tmp.png");`

Like you would do on other platforms, and use a file from there.

You can also use `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a real problem, but as you can see in my question the problem is not with the Save but before, with the AsJPEG (it returns null)